# Prevent repositioning on jQuery droppable {over}

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Here's a fiddle: [click me](http://jsfiddle.net/ddxj3/3/) (you'll need to refresh to make it  bug out again, it's just a simple demonstration)

I have some drag and drop elements that I want to be able to nest. I have it set up so that when the dragged item hovers over the droppable item, it is `.appendTo()`'d the droppable item. But that's just for the sake of DOM semantics. I also want to be able to position these items on the "canvas" (that's what we'll call it), in order to maintain their dragged position.

It works, with one quirk: whenever the draggable is `.appendTo()` the droppable, the draggable shifts erratically based on its relative position before the hover event.

For example, say A is dragged to be placed inside of B. When A is hovering over B, A is appended to B and the position that A had relative to its original parent now carries over, so since B is its new parent, A instantly moves to the relative position it was at when it was within its original parent.

How can I keep A from moving?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this line, *both* your div's become draggable and droppable. You sure that this is what you want ?

```
$('div').draggable(); 
$('div').droppable({});
```

`over` event handler is meant to be used for when an element is *hovering* over a droppable. Why would not use `drop` event handler to do the job ?

```
    over: function (event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));
    }
```

You could do the following by changing your `over` callback to look like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/mXju8/), but then again the entire solution could be rewritten without any custom logic, by utilizing what's already provided by jQueryUI api.

> When A is hovering over B, A is appended to B and the position that A
>   had relative to its original parent now carries over,

But, if what you want is specifically a draggable that can be added to a droppable during `dropover` event. Then we can work out an example. If you just want to drop stuff in a container and be able to keep track of the order + keep everything visually aligned then you should use a `sortable` widget instead.